# Conditional Formatting - Multi-conditional, InStr-check, lowest value

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

If have the following ListObject/Table in my Excel Spreadsheet and I want to highlite the cheapest price for each row. This works quite well with the following conditional formatting formula:

> =IF(F3<>"",F3=MIN($F3:$AC3),"")

Applies to:

> =$F$3:$I$14

[image]

What I additionally need is that whenever there is a value in a Column starting with "AAA" (in this case column [F] or [G]) this value should be highlighted, eventhough there might be a lower value in another column. But this rule should only be applied if in column [D] the value is "A".

I struggled longer now and have no result for that.
Your help is highly appreciated.

What I tried so far is this formula, but this is just the beginning and does not work:

> =IF(AND(D3="A",F3<>""),"",IF(F3<>"",F3=MIN($F3:$AC3),""))

This does not even include the Instr-check...
But if the InStr check is too complicated it would also be OK to take column [F] and [G] as fixed.

Edit:
It does not occur that both column [F] and [G] are filled. It is always either or.

I tried also to create a second conditional formatting rule and put that rule at position 1:

> =IF(AND(D3="A",F3<>""),TRUE,FALSE)

that does work, but still checks for the cheapest price in the row.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=IFERROR(AND(F3>0,F3=SEARCH("A",$D3)*F3*1/SEARCH("AAA",F$2)^-1),IF(F3<>"",F3=MIN($F3:$AC3),""))
```

Oh my bad, it's highlighting two on a row, will fix and update.

Comment: thanks for you prompt solution. it works not 100%, additionally to the column with "AAA" in it, it still does highlight a cheaper price in the same row. So now it highlights 2 prices.

Comment: Yeah, I caught the second highlight after posting.  Struggling though because all memory of the A and AAA are lost on subsequent cells in the row.

Comment: hmm.. I have also no solution so far. What about using 2 different formula instead of one big?

Comment: Certainly try it - the problem I've encountered is that the condition of one is not known to the other.  There's going to be a clever way to do this but I'm putting my efforts into a very non-clever way.

Comment: I tried to do 3 formulas, like above in my 2nd screenshot. and for the Main-check (the green highlights) I changed to formula to: =IF(D3<>"A",IF(F3<>"",F3=MIN($F3:$AC3),""),FALSE)
but it does not work somehow... I let Excel check whether column [D] is NOT "A", so only then it should proceed further... I don't get it.

Comment: ok got it! in combination with this little gem (=$D3="A") -> Format cells with NO HIGHLIGHTNING, applied to columns [H] to [AC] as an extra rule above your posted rule, every cell after Range [F:G] will be highlighted white when column [D] has value "A". I will mark you answer as helpful in combination with mine.

Comment: Oh man, another one of those, "Why didn't I think of that ideas" - glad you got it!!