# Conditional Formatting - Multi-conditional, InStr-check, lowest value (part 2)

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I asked a question back in 2019 and I remember I was asked once to create a just a new question instead of pulling the old one back and ask a second one in there.
--> [Conditional Formatting - Multi-conditional, InStr-check, lowest value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57003689/conditional-formatting-multi-conditional-instr-check-lowest-value)

My use case needs to be adjusted and I am struggling again with that one.
If have the following ListObject/Table in my Excel Spreadsheet and I want to highlite the cheapest price for each row. This works quite well with the following conditional formatting formula:
[image]

What I additionally need is that whenever there is a value in a Column starting with "AAA" or "XXX" (in this case column [H], [I] or [J]) this value should be highlighted, eventhough there might be a lower value in another column. But this rule should only be applied if in column [D] the value is "A". For simplicity those special treated columns are always starting from column [H] and ongoing. They are not occuring in between somewhere.

It does not occur that both column [H] and [I] are filled. It is always either or. But column [J]
can have values additionally.

What I have so far:

[image]

```
=$D3="A"
```

Formats cells with NO HIGHLIGHTNING, applied to columns [J] to [AC] as an extra rule above the next rule below, every cell after Range [H:J] will be highlighted white when column [D] has value "A".

@ProfoundlyOblivious helped me with the major formula:

```
=IFERROR(AND(H3>0,H3=SEARCH("A",$D3)*H3*1/SEARCH("AAA",H$2)^-1),IF(H3<>"",H3=MIN($H3:$AC3),""))
```

What is not working is that in row 2184 to 2189 for example there is no highliting at all. It should highlight the values in column [H] because they are clearly the lowest one. But somehow the major formula needs to be adjusted.

edit: my try was this one, but it misses some rows. The dark green ceels in the rows 2184 to 2189 are visible now, but it misses some if the cheapest price is in column [I] though.

```
=IF(J3<>"",J3=MIN($H3:$J3),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Column headers on the first screenshot are different then those used in the post, last screenshot doesn't have column headers at all and it makes understanding your problem difficult. One conditional rule should be enough to cover all cases but you need to present the algorithm of CF in a clear way.

Comment: you're right, sorry for that. I edited my post.

Comment: The range to color contains only empty cells or values>0. You want to color minimum value in row. If column D is equal to "A" then only check columns with "AAA" or "XXX" at start of column header. Is it correct?

Comment: cells in a row can have either empty cells or values aboe 0. If column [D] contains value "A" then the columns with header partially "AAA" and "XXX" in it should be considered only for the "what is the lowest price". If column [D] has value "B" then the whole row (starting from column [H] to infinite) should be consideres for the "what is the lowest price" finding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single rule with the following formula:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/FREQUENCY(0.01,
($H3:$T3)*((($D3<>"A")+(LEFT($H$2:$T$2,3)="AAA")+(LEFT($H$2:$T$2,3)="XXX"))>0)),
COLUMN($H$2:$T$2))=COLUMN()
```

Sample result with some random data:
[image]

`FREQUENCY` returns an array similar to: `{0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}` where `1` indicates the position of the cell in row with the smallest value greater than or equal to `0.01` (use `1E-300` if you have values lower than `0.01`)

Multiplication by `((($D3<>"A")+(LEFT($H$2:$T$2,3)="AAA")+(LEFT($H$2:$T$2,3)="XXX"))>0)` zeroes all cells that do not meet any of the conditions:

- row header is equal to "A"
- column header starts with "AAA" or "XXX"

`LOOKUP` ignores `1/0` errors and finds the position of the only `1` returned by `FREQUENCY` and returns corresponding column number.

Comment: I have issues with all cases not having "A" in column [D]. it marks values which are not the lowest which is odd, because it works for you.

Comment: I tested arround and the behaviour is somewhat strange. values are in the near same range, like 590 to 699. the wrong value will be marked. if a test a call with 500 or 400 nothing changes. but if I set a value like 100, then it marks the correct one. edit: the lowest value i have to choose when testing is exactly 50% of the second lowest one.

Comment: can you test your example having the last column the lowest value when [D] isn't 'A'? chose a value which is not so far away from the second lowest one. thanks . exactly this does not work for me.

Comment: @smartini I have fixed an obvious error in the formula - the part described in the _Multiplication by_ paragraph. It was multiplying values in some cases by 2, instead of 0 or 1 (depending on OR condition). I am not sure if this mistake could cause problems in the last column, but please test it now. If for some reason it still produces unexpected result - please edit the question and add exact values reproducing the issue and let me know.

Comment: not that obvious to me though, really tried to understand every piece of the formula but formulas and me won't get friends this life. It works like a charm now! I will mark your answer as a proper solution. thanks!